# How to access C++ Namespaces and Classes with Python ctypes

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

I have a C++ library with the following Namespace and classes:

```
namespace avdecc_lib
{
    class net_interface;
    class controller;

    class system
    {
      public:
         enum system_type
         {
            LAYER2_MULTITHREADED_CALLBACK,
         };
    }
    extern "C" AVDECC_CONTROLLER_LIB32_API system * STDCALL create_system(system::system_type type, net_interface *netif, controller *controller_obj);
```

I want to use the follwing call in Python with ctypes:

```
sys = avdecc_lib::create_system(avdecc_lib::system::LAYER2_MULTITHREADED_CALLBACK, netif, controller_obj);
```

I tried this without success:

```
self.avdecc_lib = cdll.LoadLibrary("path/to/lib.so")
self.sys = self.avdecc_lib.create_system(self.avdecc_lib.system.LAYER2_MULTITHREADED_CALLBACK,self.netif,self.controller_obj)
```

The library is loaded and the the objects generated successfully, but I have no indication what is going wrong with the function call.

How can I access `avdecc_lib::system::LAYER2_MULTITHREADED_CALLBACK`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enum constants are not exported from libraries, so there's no way to find them at runtime. Your only option is to determine the numeric value based on the headers. If the constant hasn't been explicitly assigned a value, it's one more than the previous constant, or 0 if it's the first constant in the enumeration.

By the way, your function has been declared with STDCALL calling convention, but cdll uses CDECL calling convention. You'll need to use windll to call the function correctly.